# Hibernate 5 with JPA : hibernate access without schema spécified in entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a MAVEN + SPRING + JPA + HIBERNATE + MSYQL application.
I want to upgrade hibernate 4.3.11 to the last version of hibernate v5.

before

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

after

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to access to a entity which table isn't in default schema, I have a error.
Before the upgrade, it was good.
Access a entity which table is in default schema works with V5 hibernate.

Default schema is "roles" but in all the entity of my application, I explicit the schema in @table JPA Annotation.
Even if schema is "roles"

The Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="modeler",name="concept")

public class Concept {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false,  updatable = false)
private int idconcept;

@Column(name="action_date", nullable=false)
protected LocalDate actionDate;

...

public Concept() {}

...

}
```

When I try a read access with this entity, I have the Java error:

> Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

```
In the stack, the cause is: 
         "errorCode": 1146,
        "nextException": null,
        "sqlstate": "42S02",
        "localizedMessage": "Table 'roles.concept' doesn't exist",
        "message": "Table 'roles.concept' doesn't exist",
        "suppressed": []
```

in the log of hibernate, I saw the SQL order doesn't contain the schema.

```
Sql order with hibernate 5 

    select concept0_.idconcept as idconcep1_0_, concept0_.action_date a saction_d2_0_, ..., from concept concept0_

Sql order before with hibernate 4.3.11

    select concept0_.idconcept as idconcep1_0_, concept0_.action_date a saction_d2_0_, ..., from modeler.concept concept0_
```

When I try to persist the entity, I have an error in the same theme but on the hibernate_sequence table

> Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work

```
In the stack, the cause is 
        "errorCode": 1146,
         "nextException": null,
         "sqlstate": "42S02",
        "localizedMessage": "Table 'roles.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist",
        "message": "Table 'roles.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist",
        "suppressed": []
```

in the log of hibernate, the SQL order doesn't contain the schema.

```
     select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update

--> but, it's seems that it's the same schema problem as in read access.
```

So I tried to find a solution before my question.
I found on hibernate site that version v5.0.8 was stable and tried it.
I had the same problem with it.

So I read the evolutions of the V5.0.8.
The only change which have focused my attention was : Naming strategies
I modified my xml spring configuration with some solution find on the web .
But, it doesn't work.

Extract of my `xml spring` configuration

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:config/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="demoRestPersistence" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="restDemoDS" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        </bean>
    </property>
    
     <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl" />
        </map>
    </property>
    
</bean>

<bean id="restDemoDS"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roles" />
    <property name="username" value="***" />
    <property name="password" value="******" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184025/what-are-the-jpa-table-annotation-catalog-and-schema-variables-used-for) but probably not really a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

So I found the problem.

Since version 5 of hibernate (don't know why and what), if you access to a database MySQL with several schema, this annotation is no correct anymore:

```
@Table(schema="modeler",name="concept")
```

You have to complete the annotation with the parameter `catalog`

```
@Table(catalog="modeler",schema="modeler",name="concept").
```

With this complement, the application runs. More information on the catalog property can be found in the [hibernate user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)